# Drupal not detecting updated Trusted Host Settings

Tags: security

I've installed Drupal 8 via Softaculous, and after I logged in for the first time, I see a message:

> TRUSTED HOST SETTINGS Not enabled The trusted_host_patterns setting is
>   not configured in settings.php. This can lead to security
>   vulnerabilities. It is highly recommended that you configure this. See
>   Protecting against HTTP HOST Header attacks for more information.

I edit `/drupal-install-dir/sites/default/settings.php` and add:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^smith\.technology8\.com$',
];
```

in order to make `smith.technology8.com` a trusted site.

However, after upload of `/drupal-install-dir/sites/default/settings.php` and refreshing the admin page, the original error remains.

Is there something more I need to do, or is my addition to `settings.php` incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?